# Navigation in mvvm

Tags: mvvm, navigation

I am trying to navigate on a frame with pages but instead of giving views to the page I am giving view models.

This works fine, but the problem is when I navigate between the pages the status of the radio buttons for example doesn't stay the same. It stays only if I use the views and not the view models.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about Silverlight or WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some code to explain how you navigate between each control would allow us to give you more specific answers, currently we can only guess what you are doing.

It sounds like you are creating a new instance of each ViewModel when you are navigating between pages. This of course means things such as radio buttons and control states will not remain consistent.

You could use a framework such as MVVM Light and make use of their ViewModelLocator pattern. This means you could have one static instance of each ViewModel.

You could also store all of these states in a simple data model, and then simply have your new ViewModel instance refer to this model and update it's check boxes etc appropriately.

Comment: Thanks.
I do need more the 1 instance of each so i guess i'll have to make data models in order to save each button.